# BizTalk Decide Shape Expression To Insert the Records into DB

Tags: expression, biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I have to insert SPCIFICchild record values into a table, when if
 `msg.SPECIFICchildrecord.rows.count > 1` ,

For this I would like to use decide shape with the condition `msg.SPECIFICchildrecord.rows.count > 1` Could you please any one suggest me, what would be the expression I have to give in Decide shape.

Answer (score 0):

The expression would be `msg.SPECIFICchildrecord.rows.count > 1`